# RecordFuture future.get() did not return (seldom)

Tags: intel-edison, kaa

I run a KaaClient on intel edison with temperature sensor, and updating the temperature onto KaaServer, but sometimes when I start or resume the client, it will hang on

`RecordInfo recordInfo = future.get();`

After investigating log, I was wondering if it is becuase that I sent the information to server[2] between those logs[1][3]:

[1] **[pool-68-thread-1]INFO o.k.k.c.c.i.DefaultOperationDataProcessor - Created Sync request:** {"requestId": 1, "syncRequestMetaData": ,...

[2] **[Thread-47] INFO  c.i.i.k.e.k.KaaModbusComponent-[readTemperature] sent log record to server**

[3] **[pool-68-thread-1] INFO  o.k.k.c.c.i.c.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - ConnAck (ACCEPTED)** message received for channel [default_operation_tcp_channel]
...

In the above sequence, [1][2][3], it will always hang on future.get();
In other sequences, such as [2][1][3] or [1][3][2], it works.

Could some expert help if it is caused by this? if yes, please help guide me what's the good way to resolve this. thanks.

Comment: Did client hang on forever? So it looks like a deadlock.

Comment: Can your provide the part of code where you call `future.get()`, for more information? For example, if you make this call in listener it may lead to such problem.